# Intermittent column does not belong to table exception

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that gets called hundreds of times per minute.  Every once in a rare while I will get an exception that a column does not exist in the query.  Here is the exception:

System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ArgumentException: Column 'SubjectID' does not belong to table .

[ArgumentException: Column 'SubjectID' does not belong to table .]
   System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName) +1775157
   System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String columnName) +13
   System.Data.DataTableReader.get_Item(String name) +66

Here is the C# that calls the stored proc:

```
DataTableReader dtr;
        dtr = Util.getDepartmentsByTerm(term);
        ddlSubject.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select A Subject...", ""));
        while (dtr.Read())
        {
            //The following line throws the exception!
            var value = (string)dtr["SubjectID"];
            var text = (string)dtr["title"];
            var count = (int) dtr["Count"];
            //if (!text.Contains("(0)"))
            if(count > 0)
                ddlSubject.Items.Add(new ListItem(text, value));
        }
```

Pretty simple... here's the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[selectDepartmentsByTerm] 

( 

@term nvarchar(50),
@version int

) 

AS     
SELECT SubjectID, Subject as Title,(select count(distinct courseno)
  from RegistrationBlock WITH (NOLOCK)
 where RegistrationBlock.Subject = Subjects.SubjectID
   and RegistrationBlock.version = @version
   and (@term = '' OR RegistrationBlock.term = @term)) as "Count"
  FROM Subjects WITH (NOLOCK)
 where Version = @version
 order by subject
GO
```

Comment: I've seen a post that said that this problem can be caused by a corruption in the connection pool. Make sure that your connections are all being closed properly. You can read some more ways to diagnose/fix the problem here: http://www.ksvali.com/2010/08/solution-to-random-error-column-does-not-belong-to-table/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom H.'s comment on my question solved this:

> I've seen a post that said that this problem can be caused by a corruption in the connection pool. Make sure that your connections are all being closed properly. You can read some more ways to diagnose/fix the problem here: http://www.ksvali.com/2010/08/solution-to-random-error-column-does-not-belong-to-table/